# uniformly continuity and boundedness of periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I have one question to understanding of boundedness of periodic function. So if we have $f$ is continuous periodic function with $f(x)=f(x+p)$ for some $p>0$ and $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$. Then $\exists \quad x'\in [0,p]$ such that $f(x)=f(x')  \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R$. Can somebody precise explain me, why does this $x'$ exist? Because I understand it only intuitively

Thank you!

Comment: The reason $x'$ exists is that any real number and be written in the form $x = py+x'$ where $x'$ is between 0 and $p$.  The follows from the division algorithm.  The remainder after dividing a number $x$ by $p$ must be smaller than $p$.